# I am trying to make my discord bot say its online, but my code isn't working (I have done every single other step for the bot)

Tags: javascript

I am running this with Command Prompt.

I have already tried going into Command Prompt, saving, and then using alternatives, like typing "node .", or "node index", or "node index.js".

```
const Discord require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('this bot is online :D');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if (msg.content === "HELLO") {
        msg.reply('HELLO FRIEND!')
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

It should be that when I go to Discord, it says my bot is on, but instead, in Command Prompt, it says this: "SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration" and it doesn't say my bot is online in Discord.

Comment: You are missing equal signs on lines 1 and 4 to assign values to your variables. `const Discord = require('discord.js')` and `const token = 'NTg.....'`

Comment: Also that token, on line 4, should be kept secret. If someone gets that they can impersonate your bot and get it ban

Comment: What text editor do you use? You should use something like VSCode, that can read your code and point out errors and give hints. You seem to have very simple errors that would be easily caught by such a program.

Comment: Regenerate your token and don't show your token in public

Comment: You're missing some = in your code

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple equal signs in your code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Equal sign was missing here
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'SUPER SECRET YOU SHOULD NEVER REVEAL TO THE WORLD'; // Equal sign was missing here
```

I tested with your token and the bot worked.